# Makefile match anything rule as intermediate

Tags: makefile, gnu

Consider this simple Makefile:

```
%.one: %.two
    echo one
%.two: %.three
    echo two
%.three: %.four
    echo three

all: hi.one
```

As expected, `make all` will produce:

```
echo three
three
echo two
two
echo one
one
```

But if I make an intermediate rule without any prefix/suffix:

```
%.one: %
    echo one
%: %.three
    echo one
%.three: %.four
    echo one

all: hi.one
```

Make will fail saying there is no rule to make `hi.one`. Is this simply impossible with Make?

Comment: does `hi.four` exist?

Comment: Yes it does exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this isn't possible, non-terminal match-anything rules are ignored for dependencies of pattern rules.

This isn't actually mentioned in the manual, but the following comment in the make source ([implicit.c:321](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/implicit.c)) makes it clear

```
      /* Rules that can match any filename and are not terminal
         are ignored if we're recursing, so that they cannot be
         intermediate files.  */
```

Comment: This makes me sad.

Comment: @CinoltYuklair Well there's no reason for your example to use a match-anything rule; there's almost certainly a better way of handling whatever it is you're really trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Binary files in UNIXes dont have any prefix/suffix, so a binary file in the current directory would use simply `%` in a pattern rule.

Comment: @CinoltYuklair Sure, but why would a binary file be a target of a pattern rule?

Comment: %: %.o
  gcc -o $@ $^

Comment: What I meant was why would you need something like `%.one: %`?

Comment: For example `anotherdir/%: %; cp $< $@`

Comment: Use a static pattern rule `anotherdir/exe: anotherdir/%: %`