# Pattern rule not found in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

Let's say I have this minimalist *main.c* program

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

and this *Makefile*

```
.PHONY: %.run

%.run: %
    ./$<
```

If I run the following command

```
make main.run
```

which, I expect, would

1. make the *main* executable from *main.c* (using `make` default implicit `%: %.c` rule)
2. execute *main*
3. exit succesfully.

But what I get instead is the following error

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'main.run'.  Stop.
```

I tried to disable default implicit rules and set my own compile rule with

```
.SUFFIXES:

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

but this doesn't help.

However, in both cases, if I run `make main` first, then `make main.run`, it is working as expected. But running two commands is exactly what I am trying to avoid with my `%.run` rule.

Of course if I replace my pattern rule with this explicit rule

```
main.run: main
    ./main
```

it is working.

Also, if I change my pattern rules to `%.x: %.c` and `%.run: %.x` with a *.x* suffix for the executables, this is working, but again I don't want suffixes.

Of course, my question is not to know if this is the right way to compile and run a program in one command, it is really to know why this Makefile does not execute the way I am expecting.

Comment: Please show the working versino without implicits and without "%". Or does it not work that way either? I do not see anything which would remove main after executing by the way.

Comment: @Yunnosch you are right, I was expecting `make` to delete *main* because it was an intermediate file but it doesn't. However because this is not the main subject, I removed it from my initial question consequently to your comment. I also added the explicit rule you asked for, which is of course working.

Comment: Good question. I can repro on CentOS 5. And after you get an answer, maybe you could ask a follow-up question about `rm main`, which happens in the `%.x` version.

Comment: I can't explain why this makefile doesn't work as written, but it does work if you add `.INTERMEDIATE: main` (at least in GNUMake 3.81).

Comment: If you are on `gmake` you can just give your source code a name compatible with the executable(`foobar.c` for `foobar` executable) and use `/dev/null` as a make file like `make -f /dev/null foobar` (completely relying on implicits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear the restrictions of the [Match Anything Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules) for targets also apply to prerequisites, although I can not find this stated anywhere<sup>1</sup>.

If the executable `main` *already* exists, the OP's makefile:

```
%.run: %
    ./$<
```

works perfectly fine. Two ways to fix the problem are to:

- Add an explicit rule to build `main`, or
- Add an empty rule with target `main`; this will cause `main` to be built by the implicit pattern-matching rules, or an explicit rule.

We give four solutions.

**1.** The following makefile works (tested on GNU make):

```
%.run: %
    ./$<

main:
```

Here the word `main` is hard-coded in the makefile. You could handle adhoc targets via:

```
RUN_TARGETS = main.run foo.run bar.run $(filter %.run,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

%.run: %
    ./$<

$(RUN_TARGETS:.run=) dummy:
```

(We need `filter` to ensure that a typo such as `make claen` returns an error message. `dummy` is used to avoid an empty target list.)

**2.** Another variation is to use a [Static Pattern Rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html), which seems to bypass this bug/feature:

```
RUN_TARGETS = main.run foo.run bar.run $(filter %.run,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

$(RUN_TARGETS) dummy.run: %.run: %
    ./$<
```

**3.** And yet another way is to use a *terminal* match-anything rule, *if* all your executables can be built from a *single* C file, as per the built-in rules. This also deletes `main` after running, for whatever reason:

```
%.run: %
    ./$<

%:: %.c  # note double-colon, for terminal match-anything rule
    cc $< -o $@
```

**4.** Finally, a completely different way to resolve the problem is to handle the prerequisite explicitly by invoking make recursively:

```
%.run:
    make $*
    ./$*
```

---

For somewhat-related questions, see [GNU make seems to ignore non-terminal match-anything rules for intermediate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481042/gnu-make-seems-to-ignore-non-terminal-match-anything-rules-for-intermediate-file) and [Force make to use a more specific rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842851/force-make-to-use-a-more-specific-rule/28843002#28843002).  Note that putting `main` as prerequisite to an unrelated rule, such as:

```
%.run: %
    ./$<

garbage: main
```

does not seem to work.

<sup><sup>1</sup> But see perhaps [Makefile match anything rule as intermediate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823656/makefile-match-anything-rule-as-intermediate).</sup>